# How do Galilean transformations give the idea of vector velocity additions or subtractions?

Tags: velocity, inertial-frames, galilean-relativity

I have been reading an article on [Galilean transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galilean_transformation) from Wikipedia

and encountered a sentence, quoted- 'In essence, the Galilean transformations embody the intuitive notion of addition and subtraction of velocities as vectors.' from the 1st paragraph under 'Translation' section. How does the Galilean transformation give such notion? Is this by taking time derivatives of the position coordinates such as

$\dot x' = \dot x - v$

which does seem to give the idea, but then again I am not sure. Doesn't this cause the position of the point to change with time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here’s an image to help with understanding the same. [image]

We have frame $S$ and frame $S’$ with a relative velocity of $\vec v$ whose origins coincided at $t=0$. Say there’s an event which in $S$ is at $\left(\vec x,t\right)$ and in $S’$ is at $\left(\vec x’,t’\right)$. Now I order to relate the observations between the frames, we can see that given $t=t’$, the two displacements are just related by a simple vector addition. Namely $$\vec x’=\vec x + \vec vt$$

Comment: So your explanation gives the idea in case of displacement vectors. What about velocity vectors? Is this by taking time derivatives of the position vectors?

Comment: Yes. Just the derivative. Because  the relative velocity is constant (inertial frame) at each instant of time the displacements are varying linearly. This is why we can add them. And since addition is different directions don’t mix up, we can add them vectorially.